# Mapping dynamic JSONB to fixed table in postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

My problem is quite simple. I have a postgres function that returns multiple, flat JSONB objects with different keys as such:

```
{key1: "value1a"}
{key1: "value1b", key2: "value2b"}
{key2: "value2c"}
```

And I would like to represent these objects as a table, unioning all JSONB objects, so that "normal" (non JSONB) postgres operations can be performed on them, as if they were a table:

```
key1    | key2
------------------
value1a | NULL
value1b | value2b
NULL    | value2c
```

Essentially, I want a postgres function with dynamic return values, which I know is impossible. I have seen some work-arounds with 2-step function, but these do not seem so feasible. Ideally the user should just have one postgres function and not know that behind it are JSONB objects.

Is this possible, or are there any ideas as to how to achieve this?

Comment: `jsonb_each()`? https://rextester.com/GVG17744

Comment: That does not work, because the exact columns in the table (the output) is only known at runtime (by selecting another query) and thus you need a function with dynamic output - which is impossible like I mentioned.

You can write a query that does this indeed (like you mentioned) but I would like to hide implementation details of the query inside a function or something similar. Does that make sense?